# Python: Comment out a block heading without dedenting all the code inside

Tags: python, indentation, comments

Sometimes I need to temporarily comment out block headings for testing purpose, e.g.:

```
i = 2
s = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }

#while i > 0:
  s.pop()
  i -= 1

print(s)
```

but, since indentation is part of python's syntax, if I run the code above I got:

```
    s.pop()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I know that dedenting the code inside the commented `while` would make it work, but I'd like to preserve a visual structure of my code instead of dedenting and indenting it each time.

Are there any trick to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to run the code inside the block exactly once, instead of some number of times dictated by the loop header. It's hard for me to imagine a situation in which this is useful, especially since the loop header often sets up variables that are used within the loop (e.g. `for x in y:` makes `x` available to the loop body).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I presume the example given is not true to life, though the challenge presented by the post does make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about `if True:` as the alternate?  Then just exchange the '#' between the `while` and `if` to get your desired effect.

Comment: `if True:` is what I always use for these cases.  And, to comment out a whole block, I put `if False:` the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Either use an editor that auto-indent for you or replace the while by something like `if True:` temporarily.